# Incorrect texture mapping when using DRACOLoader

Tags: three.js, gltf

I'm trying to use Draco to compress models in gif format, but I get a problem with displaying textures (http://prntscr.com/wcgz20 - without compression, http://prntscr.com/wch12k - with compression). Squeezing through the blender (http://prntscr.com/wch055). I tried different settings, the result was the same. I did the download for example https://sbcode.net/threejs/loaders-draco/

Comment: Try importing your model to https://threejs.org/editor/ what do you see?

Comment: If you're exporting the Draco-compressed files from Blender, note that older versions of Blender had [a bug](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/1079) causing compressed UVs to be incorrect. You may want to try updating to the latest version of Blender, or adding Draco compression with glTF-Pipeline or glTF-Transform instead.